# How do I compress and split files with terminal?

Tags: archive

So what I wanted to do is compress files (using `7zip`) and split a 600MB folder into 199MB parts, but sadly when I tried to do this task with archive manager it gave me an error, but I know that if I use terminal it will work.

I looked this up in askubuntu and found out about this command:

```
7z a -v5m -mx0 ubuntu.7z
```

I understand that `v5m` will split it to 5 mb parts and `-mx0` means that it will not compress it, but I want it to compress so what should I write  instead of this `-mx0`?

Please note: I am using `7zip` because I most probably will use this file on a Windows pc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MX you can set the level of compression used.

Set it to 9 for maximum compression.

See `man 7z` for further explanations.